# Downloading Fritz

Tags: software, fritz

My apologies if this has been asked already - I couldn't found it though. I have been trying to download Fritz, the chess game analyzer, and I have been tirelessly searching on the internet for ways to do so, but to no avail. Does anybody know where I could do so? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why Fritz in particular?

Comment: There are better engines like StockFish & Houdini, as for Fritz, old versions are included with Chessbase producto.

Answer (score 3):

It's available on [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/276750/) (Fritz Chess 14*), or the [ChessBase shop](http://shop.chessbase.com/en/products/deep_fritz_14_english) (Deep Fritz 14).

---

*The Steam version is *significantly* cheaper. The developer makes some [claims](http://steamcommunity.com/app/276750/discussions/0/522729358349936600/#c522729359455994991) in a discussion thread that it's equivalent to true Deep Fritz (with the multicore 64-bit support enabled). I'm not sure if that's actually the case, though; the price reduction is suspicious, and historically Fritz Chess has been released as a watered-down version of Deep Fritz, so I'd be careful with that. Make sure you know what you need and what you're actually buying.